# FasterCSV error /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/fastercsv-1.5.4/lib/faster_csv.rb:1641:in `shift'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

Newbie to ruby this is my first project I am using the FasterCSV Gem and absolutely love the speed.

I have found one problem that when a field is too long it throws up an error below:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/fastercsv-1.5.4/lib/faster_csv.rb:1641:in `shift': FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError (FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError)

The error is on the second line first line is read correctly :-)

"1013197145","PSION HU6020 Hand Strap","1","1","10"

"1013197542","HP ProBook NA920EA_KT931AT 39.6 cm (15.6") Notebook - Intel Core 2 Duo T6570 2.10 GHz - 1366 x 768 WXGA Display - 2 GB RAM - 250 GB HDD - DVD-Writer LightScribe - Intel GMA 4500MHD Graphics Card - Bluetooth - Webcam - Genuine Windows Vista Business - 5 Hour Battery - HDMI","1","1","10"

here is my code:

```
FasterCSV.foreach(file_path, {:col_sep=> colsep, :quote_char => char}) do |row|

   my.query("INSERT INTO product_prices (partno,costpriceexvat,sku, supplierid) VALUES ('#{row[7]}', '#{row[8]}', '#{row[3]}','1')")

end
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this has nothing to do whatsoever with FasterCSV choking on long strings and everything with the inch character in the “(15.6")” part of your item description – as it is identical to the quote, it terminates the CSV value, thus making for a malformed CSV line. FasterCSV [is designed to be strict](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/files/README.html) about this kind of things.

Comment: Thanks you seem to be correct i went with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'public/files/EN_UK_B_productdescriptions.csv' INTO TABLE temp_productdescriptions  instead of fastercsv :(

Comment: Glad my answer helped pinpoint the issue. However, in their current form, both it and your question are not of great general use as future reference to StackOverflow users. Would you care to reword your question to be more generic (along the line of “Possible causes for FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError” maybe)?

Comment: Yes sorry new here didn't even think of that :S

basically my rows contained may characters in the text that could be mistaken for column or quote terminators. FasterCSV is unable to handle this as kopischke pointed out so the only alternative for me was to bulk insert the data directly into mysql.

Hope this clears things up a bit!